# Why I can not clearInterval in the following example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have the following issue. While the `timer_mou` starts counting, when the `pause` equals `closeit` it does not clear the interval.

What am I missing here?

```
function my_timer(pause){
    console.log('function: '+pause);

    var timer_mou = setInterval(function() { 
        console.log('counting');
    }, 5000);  

    if (pause == 'closeit') { 
        clearInterval(timer_mou); 
    }     
}
```

Comment: why is closeit in the if statement a string?

Comment: @sachsure i am quite beginner in javascript. can you explain me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the `setInterval` out of the pause function to define the variable `timer_mou` in the global scope, then when you call your function it will clear it correctly, instead of defining it on every call of the function, check the working example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
var i = 0;
var timer;

start();

$('#pause').on('click',function(){
  pause()
})

$('#restart').on('click',function(){
  restart()
})

function pause(){
  clearInterval(timer);  
}

function restart(){
  i=0;
  pause()
  start();
}

function start(){
  timer = setInterval(function() { 
    i++;
    console.log('Counting '+i);
  },1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='pause'>Pause</button>
<button id='restart'>Restart</button>
```

Comment: please explain the reason (they are clearing a new interval everytime but the original interval will be running infinitely as a zombie.)

Comment: What exactly did you add to his code, except this majestic jquery?

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @K.Daniek , The OP code define the interval in every call of the function instead of the global scope definition...

Comment: Thank you for this. I am using an extra if `pause=='openit'` to restart the interval using `setInterval` without luck. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah that's it. But I just don't see the point of adding jquery in here but anyways that's a good problem solution. Have a nice day

Comment: You're welcome, i'm not sure what you want to restart exactly @Xalloumokkelos (Do you've an incrementing variable inside the interval?)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes I have an incrementing variable that I need to restart the `timer_mou`

Comment: I suggest to use functions `start/pause/restart` as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `timer_mou` outside of the function. In your case you won't be able to clear the timer as you have lost reference to the timer and you create a new timer instance with every function call.

Try something like:

```
var timer_mou;

function start_timer() {
  timer_mou = setInterval(function() { 
    console.log('counting');
  }, 5000);
}

function stop_timer() {
  clearInterval(timer_mou);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying problem that has to do with **scope**. When you declare the setInterval inside of your function, the only place you can clear it is inside of that iteration of the function. So,

```
my_timer("") //Starts a timer in the function
my_timer("closeit") //Starts a timer in the function, then stops it 
//with the other timer running in the background
```

You can reduce the problem to the fact that your interval gets declared multiple times, and you can only stop it inside of the function. So, if you want the my_timer function to start the timer, but stop if you give it the parameter of "pauseit", you could implement something like this:

```
function my_timer(pause){
    console.log('function: '+pause);

    if(typeof timer_mou === "undefined"){ //If the interval already exists, don't start a new one
            timer_mou = //Defines in global scope
            setInterval(function() { 
               console.log('counting');
        }, 5000);  
    }
    if (pause == 'closeit') { 
        clearInterval(timer_mou); 
    }     
}
```

So, in the new version of your function, it checks if the interval is defined, and if not, defines it in the **global scope** so you can remove it later.

Done on mobile, so that's my excuse for bad formatting and spelling errors.